Convert an .xml fil to .tif in ArcGIS Pro
Using ArcGIS Pro 3.3.
I downloaded Sentinel 2a data from Copernicus, a few months ago.
trying them out today and finding that I have XML and JPEG files, no TIFF.
this is what my Copernicus data looks like once loaded in ArcGIS Pro:

I have tried spatial analysis tools and ArcHydro, respectively, with work flow:
Fill -> Flow Direction -> Flow Accumulation.
My output in hydro tools and spatial analysis tools are very similar to one another.
UNFORTUNATELY,
they do not match where the rivers/streams are according to the OpenStreetMap basemap, and the Irish EPA river layer (from living atlas):

image: hydro tools, purple. spatial analysis tools, red. OSM and Ireland epa, blue.
I tried: from contents -> right click, data -> export raster, as .tif.
that gave me this 'file system raster' & this produces the same wrong results as before:

What are smoothest options to fix this?
Is there a way to convert XML to TIFF in ArcGIS?
(online free converters did not seem to work.)
(If possible, would like to avoid downloading my several dates of data from Copernicus again).

Xml is not an image format, so no. But it may help if you edit your question and add whatever the content of the xml is.

And please describe what exactly does not match, the jpg, or the results of your analysis? Are you sure the osm basemap is correct in this area?

The data that you need for Sentinel-2 is inside GRANULE > L1C_... > IMG_DATA. There you will have all .jp2 files of each band that you can convert to .tif
